# Sequel default example fails when switched to postgres adapter

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I'm trying to run the Sequel example from http://sequel.rubyforge.org/. Everything works fine on sqlite, but fails when I switch to postgres.

This is the connection code:

```
DB = Sequel.connect(:adapter=>'postgres', :host=>'localhost', :database=>'testing', :user=>'postgres', :default_schema=>'sequel')
```

This is the error I get:

```
postgres.rb:145:in `async_exec': PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "items" does not exist (Sequel::DatabaseError) 
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "items" ("price", "name") VALUES (12.45377636338...
```

I'm suspecting that the issue is Sequel trying to execute INSERT INTO *"items"* instead *"sequel.items"*, even though :default_schema is correctly set.

Anyone have any idea what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Edit - this is the code used:

```
require "rubygems"
require "sequel"

# connect to an in-memory database
#DB = Sequel.sqlite
DB = Sequel.connect(:adapter=>'postgres', :host=>'localhost', :database=>'testing', :user=>'postgres', :default_schema=>'sequel')

# create an items table
DB.create_table :items do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  Float :price
end

# create a dataset from the items table
items = DB[:items]

# populate the table
items.insert(:name => 'abc', :price => rand * 100)
items.insert(:name => 'def', :price => rand * 100)
items.insert(:name => 'ghi', :price => rand * 100)

# print out the number of records
puts "Item count: #{items.count}"
```

Comment: Usually this error is a sign that you did not run your latest migrations. Try running `rake db:migrate` again.

Comment: I don't have rake set up for this, it's just a simple script. Anyway tables are created correctly, it fails on the 'insert' part.

Comment: Check existing "items" table in database.
This error occurs, when table not exist in database.

Comment: We need to see a migration showing the table names and columns plus your model, or a schema dump, plus your Sequel statement you're using to insert. This error could occur because of a model mismatch with a table, or a bad Sequel insert statement.

Comment: Please show us your code, not a link to the source code that you have since modified in some way.

Comment: @theTinMan Note that the linked-to example creates the 'items' table on the fly, so a migration is not needed.

Comment: possibly you don't have the table `items` in the database `testing`.

Comment: Added the code.
PS: As I already said, the tables get created correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing the `password` in the connect method (that's the only difference from the documentation example). Its common for the password to just be the username, so try that if you're not sure what the password is.

It's also suggested to use a different postgresql user with each project, which also makes naming the user intuitive (the project name.) That avoids potentially clashing names.

Anyway, see if this works:

```
DB = Sequel.postgres 'testing', host: 'localhost', default_schema: 'sequel', 
       user: 'postgres', password: 'postgres'
```

Comment: There is no password set on this db, connection passes (i checked the pg server log).